# How do i connect relationships of tables on power BI manually

Tags: powerbi, foreign-keys, primary-key, entity-relationship, erd

ERD relations, connecting 5 tables

i tried doing it automatically and it works but i want to do it manually, I WANT TO SEE IF I CAN ADD RELATIONSHIPS in relation with the foreign keys and primary keys to configure the relationships. so Can I manually establish relationships between 5 tables in Power BI using foreign keys and primary keys instead of automatic setup?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-create-and-manage-relationships